# Terraform - EC2 user_data and Sessions Manager (ssm-user)

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-session-manager, ec2-userdata

I am creating an **EC2 instance** on AWS with **Terraform** that contains the `user_data` parameter to **install docker** and assign it to the user ssm-user.

I don't want to enable the ssh connection (22) and I have **only enabled access via Session Manager** in System Manager.

This is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
sudo yum update -y
sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker -y
sudo usermod -a -G docker ssm-user
sudo chown ssm-user:ssm-user /home/ssm-user/.docker -R
sudo chmod g+rwx "/home/ssm-user/.docker" -R
sudo chown ssm-user:docker /var/run/docker.sock
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

However, when I access the EC2 instance via Session Manager and run the `docker ps` command I get the following error:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Why is this happening as if nothing is being executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`. it captures console output and probably has an error in your script. See more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts).

It probably says that `user 'ssm-user' does not exist`

By the way - you don't need `sudo` in `user data`. The commands are run as root

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, so I figured I'd paste in my code change to create the `ssm-user` via the user_data instead of waiting for an ssm session to start.

```bash
adduser -m ssm-user
tee /etc/sudoers.d/ssm-agent-users <<'EOF'
# User rules for ssm-user
ssm-user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
EOF
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/ssm-agent-users 
# Now adding the ssm-user works!
usermod -a -G docker ssm-user
```

I copied the code from [ssm-agent github](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/blob/6fa235ea8be7d6679b259b8fff3f367dd1695b67/agent/session/utility/utility_unix.go#L77-L81)

Normally, the ssm-user is created the first time a ssm session is started. Reference: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent-technical-details.html)

> On version 2.3.612.0 and later, the ssm-user account is created the first time a session is started on an instance. This ssm-user is the default OS user when a session starts in Session Manager, a capability of AWS Systems Manager.